# rails executable not working on yakuake app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I have Rails 3.2.11 installed on Ruby with version `1.9.3-p374` via RVM on Ubuntu 12.04. I've also installed [Yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/) app with version `2.9.8-1` which gets a drop-down terminal for me. Normally, on Gnome terminal, I can run both Ruby and Rails commands. But on Yakuake, I can run Ruby but I can't run Rails commands. Here are commands from Yakuake:

```
➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [i686-linux]
➜  ~  rvm -v
rvm 1.18.5 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
➜  ~  rails -v
zsh: correct 'rails' to 'tail' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: rails
```

In addition to all that:

- Both bash and zsh shells were tried, but same result is taken
- On the related [RVM](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/) site, Ruby and Rails commands should be run as login shell but Yakuake app has no option to run commands as login shell
- I also tried Guake terminal, an alternative to Yakuake, it has login shell option, but not a good alternative app and not start at login -although being set as startup at login-.

Comment: have you tried configuring login shell in kde konsole?

Comment: On kde konsole settings, there's no option to configure login shell. I made a mini-search and I saw that previous versions of konsole app has a main option called "Sessions" to setup login shell. But last stable version, it's removed.

Comment: ekremkrc, can you set what shell is used?

Comment: nope, I found anything about setting shell, probably I should go on Guake. I wish I could embed Gnome Terminal into Yakuake:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not force your shell to use default ruby you either need to run default manually in every new shell:

```
rvm use default
```

Or add sourcing default into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshenv`:

```
export rvm_path="$HOME/.rvm"
if [[ -s "$rvm_path/environments/default" ]]
then source "$rvm_path/environments/default"
else PATH="$PATH:$rvm_path/bin"
fi
```

Comment: Yeah, I managed to get 'rails -v' output properly. Thanks for your valuable help:)