# Can't switch another ruby versions on RVM

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-12.04, konsole

I have [Yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/) on Ubuntu 12.04 and I've faced [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798707/rails-executable-not-working-on-yakuake-app) before, it's already solved. But now I can't switch from Ruby to JRuby on RVM. When I run `rvm use jruby` it throws this error:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Comment: try `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, I had this problem the other day - I think I ended up `rvm implode`'ing and starting from scratch

Comment: it works, but each time, I need to enter this command, probably I should add it to my `.zshenv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Mikey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174034/mikey), adding `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to `.zshenv` -because of being used `zsh` in Yakuake- gets rid of the problem.